# In ionic 2 "ionic emulate ios" is so SLOW

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Does anyone know if there is an alternative to "emulate ionic ios" to prepare the app to run it on an iOS device? (Something more efficient as "cordova prepared ios" in ionic 1)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `YourIonicApp/platforms/ios` and open `YourIonicApp.xcodeproj`.

Then just run it from xCode! ;-)

**EDIT** : Angular 5 has been released, the compiler is now way faster ;-).

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 3, you can do

```
ionic Cordova prepare --pord
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 3.x:

```
ionic cordova prepare
```